# Corrupted files inside a folder; are they all from that folder or could they be from elsewhere?

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card

I found this folder on one of my SD cards:

[image: I found this folder on one of my SD cards]

I'm assuming it is corrupted data, but my questions are:

- The "analytics" folder properties (Win10) says the folder has 70.7GB of data. Could the data inside have come from other folders?

Most of it is backup, so I could probably afford to lose it. But would at least like to have the chance at recovering what is not backed up elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Directory is borked. The data could be anything , anywhere on the drive. Flash storage doesn't save data in contiguous chunks like an HD, so the corruption could be literally anywhere on the drive.

Use a file scavenger to scrape up what you can & discard the card; don't attempt to format round it. A dying SD card is not worth the effort once it starts to play up.
If the data is valuable use a data recovery service.

Lesson for the future: never store the only copy of any data on something as fragile, capricious & likely to die without warning as an SD card or USB stick.

Comment: Note that in most common filesystems, directories and filenames are stored in the filesystem metadata, not on the file itself, so if you are able to use filecarving utilities like photorec, the recovered files will not have their original names, and may not be in the original folders. that information is likely lost permanently.

Comment: I'd try to use some block-wise software to read out a complete IMAGE of the storage device content; so a SINGLE read over the entire device. Then use the image (possibly written to a replacement device) for any recovery attempts.

Comment: The strange thing is that all other folders are fine; windows successfully copied all that off the SD card. I'll certainly retire that card. Thanks for your pointers.

Comment: @Rickmakeitquick Even if Windows _thinks_ it read other files OK, I'd check that the _contents_ of them all are intact, and not just rely on metadata like filenames and sizes.

Comment: Thank you @gidds, will check that out!